# Adding a character within "bquote" in legend

Tags: r, plot, expression, legend

How can I add a word within the `bquote` in the `legend`? Using the code

```
x <- 1:100
y <- x^2
plot(x, y)
i <- 5
legend("topleft",
       legend=c(c(as.expression(bquote("X"[.(i)]))), 
                as.expression(bquote("X"[.(i)]))), col=c(1, 2), pch=c(2, 3))
```

I got
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sb6oW.png)
but i want a legend box where a word before the math expression `X5` will be placed such as `today X5`.

So I use

```
legend("topleft", legend=c(c(as.expression(bquote("today" "X"[.(i)]))),
                          as.expression(bquote("tommorrow" "X"[.(i)]))),
       col=c(1, 2), pch=c(2, 3))
```

but this gave me error. How could I get my desired legend box?

Comment: The error comes from the space, use a tilde `"today"~"X"`; an asterisk would leave no gap `"today"*"X"`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `bquote` independently of `expression`.

```
plot.new();plot.window(c(1, 100), c(1, 1e3));box()

i <- 5; j <- 6
legend('topleft', legend=c(bquote(today~X[.(i)]),
                           bquote(tomorrow~X[.(j)])), 
       col=1:2, pch=2:3)
```

[image]